# Automation testing for check-point image on map using sikuli(Java)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I am doing Automation Testing for the map. On the map, there are number of check-points or way-points (image.png) are present. I want to compare two images, one is saved in the folder and another is on webPage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `ScreenRegion` interface.  This is answered on Stack Overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384064/compare-images-using-sikuli-in-java

Comment: ok, your question needs to be updated as it's confusing.  What are you using Selenium for and what are you using Sikuli for?  Why would you be testing in Sikuli and then need to compare a screenshot with webDriver?